# proxy pass websocket in nginx multiple location block

Tags: nginx, websocket

I have 3 services running on my machine. I want to manage them with nginx in such way:
service-1 is running on port 6000, service-2 is running on port 6002, service-3 is a websocket that is running on port 6003.

In my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;  # Listen on IPv6
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com; 

    location /service-1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6001;
    }

    location /service-2/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6002;
    }

    location /service-3/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:65000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

}
```

The issue is, if I use "/" for websocket proxy pass then the connection establish. But using different location block doesn't establish a connection.

For example:

```
###### THIS WORKS ######

server {
    listen [::]:80;  # Listen on IPv6
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com; 

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:65000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

}


###### THIS DOESN'T WORK ######

server {
    listen [::]:80;  # Listen on IPv6
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com; 

    location /service-3/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:65000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

}
```

NB.: I am using cloudflare CDN to manage my domains and subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is that you miss request part of it in proxy part.

```
location /service-3/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:65000;
```

should look like

```
location /service-3/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:65000/service-3/;
```